# How to use findChessboardCorners and calibrateCamera?

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to use `findChessboardCorners` with `calibrateCamera` but encounter errors when using `calibrateCamera`. The output is not very helpful.

> OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (i < 0) in cv::_OutputArray::create

```
static const Size patterSize(8, 6);
auto image = imread("x.jpg", IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);

Mat corners;
auto found = findChessboardCorners(image, patterSize, corners);

//constructing objectPoints
vector<vector<Vec3f>> objectPoints;
objectPoints.push_back(vector<Vec3f>());
for (int row = 0; row < patterSize.height; row++) {
    for (int col = 0; col < patterSize.width; col++) {
        objectPoints.at(0).push_back(Vec3f(row, col, 0));
    }
}

vector<vector<Vec2f>> imagePoints;
imagePoints.push_back(vector<Vec2f>());
for (int row = 0; row < patterSize.height; row++) {
    for (int col = 0; col < patterSize.width; col++) {
        int num = row*patterSize.width + col;
        imagePoints.at(0).push_back(corners.at<Vec2f>(num, 0));
    }
}

Mat cameraMatrix, distMatrix, rvecs, tvecs;

calibrateCamera(objectPoints, imagePoints, Size(image.size().width, image.size().height), cameraMatrix, distMatrix, rvecs, tvecs);
```

Answer (score 1):

The decleration of `rvecs, tvecs` should be `vector<Mat>` rather than `Mat`, and then everything will be fine. For more information, visit [3calibration.cpp](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/3calibration.cpp).

Comment: But I think this is a solution. Though now I realize it has nothing to do with `findChessboardCorners`. Why not keep it as an answer? @IwillnotexistIdonotexist

Comment: Oh, that solved your problem? I can blow out my comment then. I'd also mark your own answer as accepted, so that it's clear that this is a solution.